# countable infinite vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, examples-counterexamples

Good night, can a countable infinite vector space $V$ on the field $\mathbb{C}$ be defined such that it has a finite base?

The spaces that I try to build fail in the property $(\alpha+\beta)v=\alpha v+\beta v$. Thanks.

Comment: Only the vector space $\{0\}$ will be countable (actually finite, so not infinite). As soon as you have a non-zero vector $v$ you will have the un-countably many elements spanned by $v$.

Comment: By the way, there is another problem that uses some of the same words as this one, but in a different order, that is quite interesting: Is there some vector space over $\mathbb{C}$ with countably infinite basis (the basis is the one that should be countable, instead of the space)?

Comment: then Does not exist such vector space ?

Comment: The one you wanted in your problem. No, there isn't.

Comment: I see thanks, in your question applies $V=\mathbb C^\infty$?

Comment: It depends. Is it the direct sum $\mathbb{C}\oplus\mathbb{C}\oplus...$ or the direct product $\mathbb{C}\times\mathbb{C}\times...$? One works, the other doesn't.

Comment: in my question, if the external operation $zv$ is non-injective, the span of v could be countable, not? why can you say that $zv$ is injective?

Answer (score 1):

No, if it's infinite it has at least two different and thereby a non-zero vector $u$. Now there's an injection(*) form the field $\mathbb C$ to $V$ defined as $c\to cu$ so the vector space must have no less cardinality than the field $\mathbb C$ which is uncountable.

Thus for a vector space to be countable it must either be $\left\{\overline0\right\}$ (making it finite) or the over which it's formed must be countable.

---

(*) To prove that the map $c\to cu$ is injective you first note that if $cu=du$ then $(c-d)u=\overline0$. If $c\ne d$ then $c-d\ne 0$ so it has an inverse so $$u = 1u = (c-d)^{-1}(c-d)u = (c-d)^{-1}\overline0 = \overline0$$
but this contradicts the assumption that $u\ne\overline0$ so the assumption $c\ne d$ must be false.

Comment: but external operation $zv$ can to be non-injective, or what do you mean?

Comment: @J.Natch No, it can't if $v\ne\overline0$, I've updated the answer with proof of that.